# Uso do DataBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

Estou implementando o databinding mas meus text's nao estao aparecendo na tela

XML:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="com.example.projetobootcamp.ui.detalhesJogo.DetalhesJogoViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/telaFundoDelalhes">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_jogo_detalhes"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_titulo_jogo_detalhes"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.454"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_titulo_jogo_detalhes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_campo_da_info"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@{viewmodel.jogoItem.title}"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_genero_jogo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_nome_jogo"
        tools:text="Nome do jogo" />
```

Meu fragment de Detalhes:

```
class DetalhesJogoFragment : Fragment() {

private val detalhesViewModel: DetalhesJogoViewModel by viewModel()
private lateinit var binding: DetalhesJogoBinding
private val argumentos by navArgs<DetalhesJogoFragmentArgs>()
private val jogo by lazy { argumentos.jogo }

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = DetalhesJogoBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    configDetalhes()
}

private fun configDetalhes() {
    detalhesViewModel.getDetalhes(jogo.id)

    Glide.with(requireContext())
        .load(jogo.thumbnail)
        .transform(CenterCrop())
        .into(iv_jogo_detalhes)

}
```

ViewModel:

```
class DetalhesJogoViewModel(
private val repository: MainRepository
) : ViewModel() {
val _jogoItem = MutableLiveData<JogoItem>()
val jogoItem: LiveData<JogoItem> = _jogoItem
val fresponse: MutableLiveData<Response<JogoItem>> = 
MutableLiveData()

fun getDetalhes(id: Int){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val response = repository.getDetalhes(id)
        fresponse.value = response
    }
}
```

A vinculação da View aparentemente esta correta, pois ela é aberta, porém nao aparecem as informações nela (dados do TextView)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para alterar os valores através do *binding* é necessário que você acesse os componentes através do *binding*.

Faça os seguintes ajustes:

1. Transforme a variável *binding* em uma propriedade da classe.
2. Ao carregar a foto, adicione os dados em *binding.ivJogoDetalhes*.

Seu código ficará mais ou menos assim:

XML

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="com.example.projetobootcamp.ui.detalhesJogo.DetalhesJogoViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/telaFundoDelalhes">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_jogo_detalhes"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_titulo_jogo_detalhes"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.454"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_titulo_jogo_detalhes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_campo_da_info"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@{viewmodel.title}"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_genero_jogo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_nome_jogo"
        tools:text="Nome do jogo" />
```

Fragmento

```
class DetalhesJogoFragment : Fragment() {

    private val detalhesViewModel: DetalhesJogoViewModel by viewModel()
    private val argumentos by navArgs<DetalhesJogoFragmentArgs>()
    private val jogo by lazy { argumentos.jogo }

    private lateinit var binding: DetalhesJogoBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = DetalhesJogoBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.viewmodel = detalhesViewModel
        configDetalhes()
    }

    private fun configDetalhes() {
        detalhesViewModel.getDetalhes(jogo.id)
        detalhesViewModel.setJogo(jogo)
        Glide.with(requireContext())
            .load(jogo.thumbnail)
            .transform(CenterCrop())
            .into(binding.ivJogoDetalhes)

    }
```

ViewModel

```
class DetalhesJogoViewModel(
private val repository: MainRepository
) : ViewModel() {
val _jogoItem = MutableLiveData<JogoItem>()
val jogoItem: LiveData<JogoItem> = _jogoItem
val fresponse: MutableLiveData<Response<JogoItem>> = 
MutableLiveData()

val title = MutableLiveData<String>("")

fun getDetalhes(id: Int){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val response = repository.getDetalhes(id)
        fresponse.value = response
    }
}

fun setJogo(jogo: JogoItem) {
   title.postValue(jogo.title)
}
```

Em relação ao *TextView*, para ser atualizado seu valor de acordo com a variável presente no seu XML, faltou apenas você passar a instância da sua *viewModel* para a variável *viewmodel* do seu XML através do *binding*.

### Configurações do gradle

É necessário também, alterar o seu arquivo *build.gradle* (Nivel do app) e adicionar o seguinte:

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
[...]
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
[...]
}

dependencies {
[...]
    // DataBinding
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'
}
```

Comment: Eu fiz algumas mudanças no codigo acima, poderia ver e me dar um feedback? Estou pegando o data no XML de um viewmodel, nao de um JogoItem mais, creio que seja assim a forma correta

Comment: Em questao da confg do meu projeto no gradle, creio que esteja correta pois estou usando o dataBindig em outra parte do cod, mas nessa parte nao utilizo o ViewModel e liveData que nem agora

Comment: Olhei o seu código mas agora fiquei em dúvida... Você está tentando implementar o _databiding_ ou _synthetics_?? Se você vai usar o _databinding_, não tem porque utilizar o _<data>_ no XML....
Para alimentar o textView você teria que fazer, `binding.tvTituloJogoDetalhes.text = "seu texto`.

Comment: Estou tentando implementar o databinding, no caso teria que deletar o data do meu XML e logo abaixo do detalhesViewModel.getDetalhes(jogo.id) colocar binding.tvTituloJogoDetalhes.text ?

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta, com a forma como teria que ficar. Talvez o _observer_ tu tenha que ajustar algo.

Comment: Fiz isso e agora deu certo, mas tu pode me tirar uma duvida? Estou começando agora a usar o DataBinding. No caso, meu codigo de antes (que nao usava Databinding) , estava muito parecido com esse que ficou agora (principalmente na fun configDetalhes()). Eu achei que iria reduzir a quantidade de codigo, principalmente dentro do detalhesViewModel.observe(), achei que eu tiraria os tvTituloJogoDetalhes.text = jogo.title e por assim vai, reduzindo a qnt de linhas, pois ja nao faz a vinculaçao direto no  Text do TextView?

Comment: Cara, peço desculpas pois me equivoquei nos conceitos.
Você está certo na questão do _\<data>_ no XML... Já arrumei minha resposta para ficar adequada ao que busca.

Comment: Sim, eu mantive e estava correto, só fiquei com aquela duvida de cima, obrigadao pela ajuda

Comment: Dessa ultima forma que voce colocou sem o binding.tvTituloJogoDetalhes.text =jogo.title nao funcionou, só esta funcionando se utilizo: detalhesViewModel.getDetalhes(jogo.id)
        detalhesViewModel.fresponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            binding.tvTituloJogoDetalhes.text = jogo.title
            binding.tvGeneroJogoDetalhes.text = jogo.genre
            Glide.with(requireContext())
                .load(jogo.thumbnail)
                .transform(CenterCrop())
                .into(iv_jogo_detalhes)
        })
    }

Comment: Confira novamente minha resposta. Pelo que entendi você está recebendo por parâmetro a instância do _jogo_ mas não está passando ela para a propriedade existente na sua viewModel __jogoItem_ e nem alimentando ela de nenhuma forma. Por isso o valor não é atualizado em tela.

Comment: conferi a vi que estava faltando algo mesmo, mas esta demorando pra atualizar ou nem atualiza os valores na view na primeira vez que clica em um jogo, tendo que sair da tela de detalhes, clicar novamente nele para carregar. Isso é normal?

Comment: Não é normal, no momento não tenho mais tempo, mas fiz uma última atualização, de uma olhada. Você terá que criar um _MutableLiveData_ para cada valor que quiser exibir, e passar ele para o componente. (Não me recordo de cabeça se tem como passar diretamente um objeto mutable para acessar seu valor)

Comment: Show cara, valeu pela ajuda, arrumou aqui